# GitHub pull request associated file and comments

Tags: git, github, count, comments, pull

I am looking for an easy way to find GitHub pull request associated file and comments? If you have suggestions or any recommendations, then please feel free to share your experience.

Comment: How about reading the commit messages on the files? They might mention GitHub pull request numbers.

Comment: Given what information and from where? A PR number and the API?  A PR number and the repository?  Something else?

Comment: Only repository given.